# Ads on my android phone

Tags: google-account

How can I stop ads from running on my phone. I tried stopping in the Google ads settings but still it is running on my fone.

Comment: Please explain what kind of ads do you want to stop: in-browser ads? in-app ads? YouTube ads? Push ads? Also, Google never provides a setting to disable ads, it just disables the *personalized* ads (you'll still get ads, but not personalized based on your preference/history).

Comment: Enough information is provided based the current methods of blocking.

Answer (score 1):

### Many Ad's support developer's and creator's on the Android platform...

Because Android is open sourced, even the Android platform is partly supported by Ads...

You either need a kernal that supports a hosts file to block on a per-host basis or you can use traffic redirection and blocking based on packets using a VPN Ad blocker...

The first option ( Hosts File ) requires root Access to modify the `system/etc/hosts` file and block advertising company's hosts or IP Addresses.

The second option is less obtrusive, you do not need root access to use a VPN Ad Blocker.. .

Please have a look around at the different options and find one that suits you best ..

[Combination of hosts files after using many ad block programs +2mb on Google Drive ... Ad-hosts.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LCjUq9D4dYplrkBOfPApY3xiRU5UJ6Xq/view?usp=drivesdk)

Ads come in 3 or 4 ways

• Internet Browser Ads

• Built-in Ads by Developers

• Ads served by Google Play Services ( Also Built-in to a degree )

You can block each type of ad in different ways depending the way it is served..

For example, built-in ads can be removed by resizing the ads code to 0.0dip in height..

Or the Ad system can be disabled by disabling Mobile Data whenever you use offline apps that have online ads within them ...

The most common methods used on Android for dismantling ads or blocking ads are in my opinion as follows...

• Mobile Data switch ( Stock )

• ABP - ( Ad Block Plus )

• VPN Ad Blockers ( Used to be heaps, however all i can find now is paid VPN Host apps )

• NO ROOT Firewall  - For forcing apps offline

• Editing the Hosts file manually

ADVANCED HACKS
Smali editing and recompilation ( reverse engineering )

• APK Tool  - Rebuild XML without Ad Code
• Lucky Patcher

Lucky Patcher will work if you know what you are doing... All apps are available on Androids... Apk tool, Lucky Patcher etc...

You can grab a safer App called 
• APK Editor 
on the play store and manually edit the XML files also ... It is only safer because it compiles with Googles Terms of Service etc... Lucky Patcher will NOT comply with the Play Store so you need to look around online .

P.S
Lucky Patcher also includes a MOCK Purchase system that can allow FREE Purchase's for almost ALL IN-APP Purchases..  IN-App Purchases are easy to MOCK by another Application by redirecting the Purchase Intent sent to the Play Store... By Wise with such a program... Shady to say the least ....

Conclusion
• Hosts files in `system/etc/hosts` is the safest method that requires no Third-party extension or additions...

VPN Blockers are also a safer method of using Ad Blockers...

Hacking is Hacking... so be careful and check your area's laws for any possible problems etc...

Android has specific terms about blocking Ads, so please look into everything appropriately.